# Post to own wall via Graph API, but make only visible to friends in same geographical area

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, geolocation, publish, privacy

Since the introduction of the smartlists feature, Facebook automatically generates a list of people in your geographical area. For me, this list is called "Berlin area".

When you manually post to your wall and restrict the receivers to this list, the resulting post includes something like this:

```
"privacy": {
  "description": "Berlin Area", 
  "value": "CUSTOM", 
  "friends": "SOME_FRIENDS", 
  "allow": "10151337424932966"
},
```

Apparently, "description" is the name of the smartlist and "allow" is its ID. Is it possible to make such a post programatically using the Graph API?

In principle, it should be possible by setting the privacy parameter of the [Post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) manually, but how do I identify the name and id of the corresponding auto-generated smart list, without having to guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the "read_friendlists" permission, the list of friend lists can be read by GETting

> https://graph.facebook.com/me/friendlists

The list we're looking for has `list_type` "current_city". In my case, there is only one such list:

```
{
  "id": "10151337424932966",
  "name": "Berlin Area",
  "list_type": "current_city"
},
```

Now I have all required information for the "privacy" parameter when doing the [Post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/). Hooray.

The privacy parameter should look like:

```
{
  "friends": "SOME_FRIENDS", 
  "allow": "10151337424932966", 
  "value": "CUSTOM"
}
```